# Writing a priority queue with a max heap structure in c++

Tags: c++, queue

I am writing a priority queue with a max heap structure as an assignment for school. I can either write it as an array or I can use a vector. I chose a vector. So the assignment is this, the user chooses options from a menu where he either wants to add,print, or view the elements. When the user chooses to add he gets ask who wants to be added, the instructor, student, or TA. He can enter i,I,t,T,S,s. The instructor having the highest priority where if the user chooses the option to print and there is an instructor in the queue he gets to go first. The TA having the second highest priority where if there is a TA and a student in the queue, the TA goes first. If there is is more than one instructor than the queue acts as a normal queue. I have written most of it, or tried. I got my max heap implementation from my textbook since they provide one. Now the problem is this, when I have more than one item in the priority queue and I choose to print, it crashes and gives me a vector subscript out of range exception. I been trying to fix it and no luck. Also, when I try to print the elements in the queue or print them, it needs to say the job# with the name of the person. Can someone help me find a way to implement that.

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>

struct Heap
{
    std::vector<int> m_elements;

    void ReHeapDown(int, int);
    void ReHeapUp(int, int);
    void Swap(int& a, int& b);
};

    #include "heap.h"

void Heap::ReHeapDown(int index, int bottom)
{
    int maxChild, rightChild, leftChild;

    leftChild = index * 2 + 1;
    rightChild = index * 2 + 2;

    if (leftChild <= bottom)
    {
        if (leftChild == bottom)
            maxChild = leftChild;
        else
        {
            if (m_elements[leftChild] <= m_elements[rightChild])
                maxChild = rightChild;
            else
                maxChild = leftChild;
        }
        if (m_elements[index] < m_elements[maxChild])
        {
            Swap(m_elements[index], m_elements[maxChild]);
            ReHeapDown(maxChild, bottom);
        }
    }
}

void Heap::ReHeapUp(int index, int bottom)
{
    int  parent;

    if (bottom  > index)
    {
        parent = (bottom - 1) / 2;
        if (m_elements[parent]  <  m_elements[bottom])
        {
            Swap(m_elements[parent], m_elements[bottom]);
            ReHeapUp(index, parent);
        }
    }
}

void Heap::Swap(int& a, int& b)
{
    int temp;
    temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}

    #include <iostream>
#include "heap.h"
#pragma once

class PQTYPE
{

private:
    Heap m_Items;

public:
    bool isEmpty() const;
    void Enqueue(int, std::string);
    void Dequeue(int, std::string);
    void printElements();
};



#include "pqtype.h"

bool PQTYPE::isEmpty() const
{
    return m_Items.m_elements.empty();
}

void PQTYPE::Enqueue(int newItem, std::string lName)
{

    if (lName == "Student")
    {
        m_Items.m_elements.push_back(newItem);
        m_Items.ReHeapUp(0, m_Items.m_elements.size() - 1);
    }
    else if (lName == "TA")
    {
        m_Items.m_elements.push_back(newItem);
        m_Items.ReHeapUp(0, m_Items.m_elements.size() - 1);
    }
    else if (lName == "Instructor")
    {
        m_Items.m_elements.push_back(newItem);
        m_Items.ReHeapUp(0, m_Items.m_elements.size() - 1);
    }
}

void PQTYPE::Dequeue(int item, std::string lName)
{
    if (isEmpty())
        std::cout << "No jobs to print\n";
    else
    {
        m_Items.m_elements[0] = m_Items.m_elements.back();
        std::cout << "Now printing Job#" << m_Items.m_elements[item - 1] << " " << lName.c_str() << std::endl;
        m_Items.m_elements.pop_back();
        m_Items.ReHeapDown(0, item - 1);
    }
}

void PQTYPE::printElements()
{
    if (isEmpty())
        std::cout << "No jobs to print\n";
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < m_Items.m_elements.size(); i++)
        {
            std::cout << "Job#" << m_Items.m_elements[i] << std::endl;
        }
    }
}


#include"pqtype.h"

struct Person
{
    int m_priority;
    std::string m_name;

    Person()
    {
        m_priority = 0;
        m_name = " ";
    }
};

int showMenu();
void addJobs(PQTYPE&, Person&);
void printJobs(PQTYPE&, Person&);
void viewJobs(PQTYPE&);

int main()
{

    int option;
    Person p;
    PQTYPE pq;

    do
    {
        option = showMenu();

        switch (option)
        {
        case 1: addJobs(pq, p);
        break;
        case 2: printJobs(pq, p);
        break;
        case 3: viewJobs(pq);
        break;
        case 4:
        break;
        default: std::cout << "Wrong input\n";
        break;
        }

    } while (option != 4);


    return 0;
}

int showMenu()
{
    int choice;
    std::cout << " 1.)Add Job\n";
    std::cout << " 2.)Print Job\n";
    std::cout << " 3.)View Jobs\n";
    std::cout << " 4.)Exit\n";
    std::cout << " Enter Choice: ";
    std::cin >> choice;

    return choice;
}

void addJobs(PQTYPE& pq, Person& per)
{
    char jobChoice;

    std::cout << "Who is the job for ( Instructor(i or I), TA(t or T), Student(s or S) :";
    std::cin >> jobChoice;

    if (jobChoice == 'S' || jobChoice == 's')
    {
        per.m_priority++;
        per.m_name = "Student";
        pq.Enqueue(per.m_priority, per.m_name);
    }
    else if (jobChoice == 'T' || jobChoice == 't')
    {
        per.m_priority++;
        per.m_name = "TA";
        pq.Enqueue(per.m_priority, per.m_name);
    }
    if (jobChoice == 'I' || jobChoice == 'i')
    {
        per.m_priority++;
        per.m_name = "Instructor";
        pq.Enqueue(per.m_priority, per.m_name);
    }
}

void printJobs(PQTYPE& pq, Person& p)
{
    pq.Dequeue(p.m_priority, p.m_name);
}

void viewJobs(PQTYPE& pq)
{
    pq.printElements();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your original code the index used inside Dequeue() for accessing the vector doesn't seem to be initialised in the right way. Let's assume that you have added two entries to your list. In this case the value of P.m_priority inside your main() is 2. Now you're calling printJobs() for the first time. printJobs() calls pq.Dequeue(p.m_priority, p.m_name), so Dequeue() gets p.m_priority as its parameter *item*. Keep in mind that *item* has the value 2.

```
m_Items.m_elements[0] = m_Items.m_elements.back();
std::cout << "Now printing Job#" << m_Items.m_elements[item - 1] << " " << lName.c_str() << std::endl;
m_Items.m_elements.pop_back();
```

You're accessing your std::vector using an index of *item - 1*. This works for the first time, as there are two elements in your list. In this call, there is also a pop_back() done on your list, which decreases its size by one. The next time you call printJobs(), the given parameter *item* won't have changed, it still has the value 2. When you access your Itemlist, there is no longer an index of 1, and an *subscript out of range* exception will be thrown.

There were no fixed priorities assigned to the three entry types in your original version, so I added these (see addJobs() ).

So a possible solution to store the person's name could look like this:

```
struct Person
{
    int m_priority;
    std::string m_name;

    Person()
    {
        m_priority = 0;
        m_name = " ";
    }
};

struct Heap
{
    std::vector<Person> m_elements;

    void ReHeapDown(int, int);
    void ReHeapUp(int, int);
    void Swap(Person& a, Person& b);
};

void Heap::ReHeapDown(int index, int bottom)
{
    int maxChild, rightChild, leftChild;

    leftChild = index * 2 + 1;
    rightChild = index * 2 + 2;

    if (leftChild <= bottom)
    {
        if (leftChild == bottom)
            maxChild = leftChild;
        else
        {
            if (m_elements[leftChild].m_priority <= m_elements[rightChild].m_priority)
                maxChild = rightChild;
            else
                maxChild = leftChild;
        }
        if (m_elements[index].m_priority < m_elements[maxChild].m_priority)
        {
            Swap(m_elements[index], m_elements[maxChild]);
            ReHeapDown(maxChild, bottom);
        }
    }
}

void Heap::ReHeapUp(int index, int bottom)
{
    int  parent;

    if (bottom  > index)
    {
        parent = (bottom - 1) / 2;
        if (m_elements[parent].m_priority  <  m_elements[bottom].m_priority)
        {
            Swap(m_elements[parent], m_elements[bottom]);
            ReHeapUp(index, parent);
        }
    }
}

void Heap::Swap(Person& a, Person& b)
{
    Person temp;
    temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}

#include <iostream>

class PQTYPE
{

private:
    Heap m_Items;

public:
    bool isEmpty() const;
    void Enqueue(Person);
    void Dequeue();
    void printElements();
};

bool PQTYPE::isEmpty() const
{
    return m_Items.m_elements.empty();
}

void PQTYPE::Enqueue(Person newItem)
{

    if (!newItem.m_name.compare("Student"))
    {
        m_Items.m_elements.push_back(newItem);
        m_Items.ReHeapUp(0, m_Items.m_elements.size() - 1);
    }
    else if (!newItem.m_name.compare("TA"))
    {
        m_Items.m_elements.push_back(newItem);
        m_Items.ReHeapUp(0, m_Items.m_elements.size() - 1);
    }
    else if (!newItem.m_name.compare("Instructor"))
    {
        m_Items.m_elements.push_back(newItem);
        m_Items.ReHeapUp(0, m_Items.m_elements.size() - 1);
    }
}

void PQTYPE::Dequeue()
{
    if (isEmpty())
        std::cout << "No jobs to print\n";
    else
    {
        Person front = m_Items.m_elements.front();
        std::cout << "Now printing Job#" << front.m_priority << " " << front.m_name.c_str() << std::endl;
        m_Items.m_elements.erase(m_Items.m_elements.begin());
        m_Items.ReHeapDown(0, m_Items.m_elements.size() - 1);
    }
}


void PQTYPE::printElements()
{
    if (isEmpty())
        std::cout << "No jobs to print\n";
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < m_Items.m_elements.size(); i++)
        {
            std::cout << "Job#" << m_Items.m_elements[i].m_priority << " " << m_Items.m_elements[i].m_name.c_str() << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

int showMenu();
void addJobs(PQTYPE&, Person&);
void printJobs(PQTYPE&, Person&);
void viewJobs(PQTYPE&);

int showMenu()
{
    int choice;
    std::cout << " 1.)Add Job\n";
    std::cout << " 2.)Print Job\n";
    std::cout << " 3.)View Jobs\n";
    std::cout << " 4.)Exit\n";
    std::cout << " Enter Choice: ";
    std::cin >> choice;

    return choice;
}

void addJobs(PQTYPE& pq, Person& per)
{
    char jobChoice;

    std::cout << "Who is the job for ( Instructor(i or I), TA(t or T), Student(s or S) :";
    std::cin >> jobChoice;

    if (jobChoice == 'S' || jobChoice == 's')
    {
        per.m_priority = 0;
        per.m_name = "Student";
        pq.Enqueue(per);
    }
    else if (jobChoice == 'T' || jobChoice == 't')
    {
        per.m_priority = 1;
        per.m_name = "TA";
        pq.Enqueue(per);
    }
    if (jobChoice == 'I' || jobChoice == 'i')
    {
        per.m_priority = 2;
        per.m_name = "Instructor";
        pq.Enqueue(per);
    }
}

void printJobs(PQTYPE& pq)
{
    pq.Dequeue();
}

void viewJobs(PQTYPE& pq)
{
    pq.printElements();
}

int main()
int option;
    Person p;
    PQTYPE pq;

    do
    {
        option = showMenu();

        switch (option)
        {
        case 1: addJobs(pq, p);
        break;
        case 2: printJobs(pq);
        break;
        case 3: viewJobs(pq);
        break;
        case 4:
        break;
        default: std::cout << "Wrong input\n";
        break;
        }

    } while (option != 4);

    return 0
}
```

Are you sure that the methods ReHeapUp and ReHeapDown meet your requirements? And shouldn't there be a distinction between job number and priority?

Comment: When I was writing this, I was saying that the job number is the priority. I was writing it so when the user would pop someone off, the PQTYPE would look at the job number as a priority. I might have confused myself and the people who viewed this because I couldn't think of another name for the member variable that I gave to the struct Person. As for the ReHeapUp and ReHeapDown, again, I thought when it gets called it would have a vector of ints that would act as the priority to put someone into the queue and then get them off because of the ints.

Comment: I didn't think I should add the struct Person in the vector because this was my first time using vectors instead of an array and I thought if I put it into the vector like this vector<Person> I wouldn't be able to access its member variables . So when I was writing down my ReheapUp and reHeapDown, I was saying I need an integer to represent the priority because the book example use integers and I would give it to the person struct that I would make then pass that member variable to the enqueue function.

Comment: Another approach to your problem could be, instead of choosing a std::vector, using a std::set accompanied by a custom compare method. Mixing up the job number and the priority doesn't sound like a good idea. What's most important is that your vector exception was caused by the item variable given to your Dequeue() method. This variable was always set to the highest priority ever assigned during runtime, while the vector's size decreased after the first Dequeue(). The second call to Dequeue() caused the exception.

Comment: I notice that you gave a fixed priority to each of the three people in the queue. Such as instructor 3, ta 2, and student 1. Is there a way where the instead of just 1 2 3. I can keep increasing the number but still make it where the instructor is always the first to dequeue then ta then student. Such as the intructor can be job#1 instructor, job#2 student, job#3 ta, job#4 instructor, job#5  ta, .... and so on. Then when you dequeue it would be job#1 instructor then job#4 instructor, job#3 ta,  job#5 ta , job#2 student,